# How Affect Resource Type Declared In Another Puppet Module

Tags: puppet

I include the class `nova::compute::libvirt` and this class defines a Package resource like so:

```
package { 'libvirt-nwfilter':
  ensure => present,
  name   => $::nova::params::libvirt_nwfilter_package_name,
  before => Service['libvirt'],
  tag    => ['openstack', 'nova-support-package'],
}
```

The problem is that the RPM is in a YUM repo that is not enabled `enabled=0`.
I could solve this issue by changing `nova::conpute::libvirt` so that Package resource looked like this:

```
package { 'libvirt-nwfilter':
  ensure => present,
  name   => $::nova::params::libvirt_nwfilter_package_name,
  before => Service['libvirt'],
  tag    => ['openstack', 'nova-support-package'],
  install_options => ['--enablerepo', 'redhat_updates'],
}
```

But I'd like to not have to modified a module I got from puppet forge because the next time someone else setups up a puppet master they might forget to make the modification.  Is there something I can do from the class that includes `nova::compute::libvirt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resource collectors](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_collectors.html#language:-resource-collectors) afford the possibility of [overriding attributes of resources declared elsewhere](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.8/lang_resources_advanced.html#amending-attributes-with-a-collector).  The syntax would be:

```
Package<| title == 'libvirt-nwfilter' |> {
    install_options => ['--enablerepo', 'redhat_updates']
}
```

That alternative avoids modifying the repository definition, and it does not require introducing any new ordering relationships.  Beware, however, that collectors always realize any matching virtual resources.  Beware also that this approach is very powerful, and thus very easy to abuse to get yourself in trouble.  With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Just curious. Please, can you explain the situation that would result in accidentally realizing virtual resources?

Comment: @RedCricket, with the specific code I presented, the only risk is that `Package[libvirt-nwfilter]` is declared as a virtual resource, and not otherwise realized for some given node.  That collector would then make the difference between the resource being realized for that node (and therefore applied) or not, which seems not to be the intention.  Risks of that sort are greater when the collector's selection predicate is less specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by enabling the `redhat_updates` yum repo with a `yumrepo` resource, and then specifying a metaparameter for it to be applied before the class.

```
yumrepo { "redhat_updates":
  baseurl  => "baseurl",
  descr    => "Redhat Updates",
  enabled  => 1,
  gpgcheck => 0,
  before   => Class['nova::compute::libvirt'],
}
```

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/yumrepo.html